# How can I dynamically update a Sequelize model definition, e.g. remove an association?

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

Is there a way to update a Sequelize 6 model so as to remove a previously added association? E.g. if I have defined MyModel.hasOne(SomeOtherModel), how do I later undo this association?

I have tried manually removing the association column via sequelize.getQueryInterface() but when i later perform a SomeOtherModel.sync({alter:true}) operation, the foreignKey column gets re-added back automatically.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at that https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/associations/belongs-to.js~belongsto#instance-method-set ?

Comment: @Anatoly I had a look at the link, but that's just an instance-saving method. It doesn't affect the definition of the foreign-key column or its constraint.

Comment: Did you try to re-register the same model?

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly, re-registering the model does indeed solve the problem, the downside being that all fields and other model associations need to be re-defined.

Comment: Unfortunately Sequelize does not provide the clear way to unregister a certain association. I'd give a more precise piece of advice if I knew what's the task about changing associations on the fly